# Creating a obj name with data in it in vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, object, vue.js

I just created a constructor function to create new Users for a JSON file.

The structure should be like:

```js
{
  "users": {
    "userName1": {
      "salary": [
        "1234"
      ]
    },
    "userName2": {
      "salary": [
        "4321"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My code looks like this atm:

```js
export const userDataControllerMixin = {
  data() {
    return {
      userObj: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    NewUser(user, salary) {
      this.user = user;
      this.salary = salary;

      user = {
        salary,
      };
    },
    // GETTING INPUT FROM USERS DIALOGBOX
    getInput(inputName, inputSalary) {

      const userName = document.querySelector(inputName).value;
      const userSalary = document.querySelector(inputSalary).value;


      const userData = new this.NewUser(userName, userSalary);
      console.log(userData);
},
```

The structur i get is wrong, it looks like this:

```js
NewUser {user: "asd ", salary: "123"}
```

Comment: Side note: You shouldn't have to use document.querySelector in a vueJS app. If you have a input use v-model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the word `this`, it means the current father, in your case `NewUser`

To get the variable the way you want, you need to do this:

```
    NewUser(user, salary) {
      this[user] = {
        'salary':salary
      };
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

In VueJS there is no need for querySelectors, since inputs are binded with v-model
Check out: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Because of that, we can reduce the app to one function, that reads the username and salary properties and adds them to the userObj.

I've made a working example here: https://codepen.io/bergur/pen/agZwQL?editors=1011

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {  
    return {
      username: '',
      salary: '',
      userObj: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    newUser() {
      this.userObj[this.username] = {
        salary: [Number(this.salary)]
      }
      
      console.log(this.userObj)
    }
  }
})
```